# Adding attendees to Outlook AppointmentItem (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, outlook, appointment

I am trying to make an application in which i can send appointments to co-workers. 
My code is as follows:

```
Public Sub SendAppointment()
    Dim TempApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application()

    'An AppointmentItem 'TempAppItem' object represent one appointment              
    Dim TempAppItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem = TempApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
    TempAppItem.Subject = Onderwerp.SelectedItem
    TempAppItem.Body = Opmerking.Text

    'Set Location
    'TempAppItem.Location = "No Location"

    'Set start and end date and times
    TempAppItem.Start = Convert.ToDateTime(Btijd.SelectedItem)
    TempAppItem.End = Convert.ToDateTime(Etijd.SelectedItem)        

    'Save to Calendar.
    TempAppItem.RequiredAttendees("some@emailaddress.com")
    TempAppItem.Send()
    TempAppItem.Save()
    TempApp = Nothing
    TempAppItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

If I leave out:

```
    TempAppItem.RequiredAttendees("some@emailaddress.com")
```

It creates the appointment in my own calendar. This proves the rest of the code works. But somehow no matter which argument i add to RequiredAttendees, I keep getting errors. Mostly saying "Too many arguments to 'Property RequiredAttendees As String'.

In my eyes the easiest would be if I can just use the users e-mailaddress as a value to a variable, but somehow it seems vb.net only uses the stored name of said contact, which doesn't seem to work :\

I can't find any explanation of how to properly set the RequiredAttendees property and I am starting to break my head over this. Can anyone help me out or at least push me in the right direction?

Comment: Why are you trying to set a property as if it's a method call? just use `=`

Comment: As said above you're probably after `TempAppItem.RequiredAttendees = "some@emailaddress.com"`. Not sure why you went with `()`.

Comment: And don't forget to call Send